# How do I display quantity select in loop in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, loops, woocommerce

I need to display quantity select near "Add to cart" button in WooCommerce in loop. How do I do that?
Thank you MahdiY, that works. But I faced another problem:
I want to replace button "Add to cart" with cart icon.
In file add-to-cart.php I have the following code:

```
global $product;
$class = isset( $class ) ? $class . ' cart-icon-btn' : 'cart-icon-btn';
$tdir = get_template_directory_uri();
echo has_filter('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link');
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s"><img class="cart-icon-btn" src="' . $tdir . '/images/basketin.png"></a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' )
        // esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
```

But this filter 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link' seems to override my HTML and remove IMG tag. I tried to find any function added to this filter in files of WC code but did not find. 
How do I fix that?

Comment: No need to delete function, just use add_filter with a big priority.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code:

```
<?php 
/**
 * Code should be placed in your theme functions.php file.
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );

function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        $html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
        $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
        $html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
        $html .= '</form>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

[Override loop template and show quantities next to add to cart buttons.](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/override-loop-template-and-show-quantities-next-to-add-to-cart-buttons/)